# How can I stabilize a berry coulis?

Tags: sauce, fruit

I made a coulis from fresh blackberries by simply using a fork and sieve. I did not cook, neither added sugar to the final juice. The creamy coulis had beautiful color and texture, however it clearly separated into a watery phase and a more granular phase. How can make the coulis a stable substance which works well for decorating a plate?

Comment: So are you just mashing blackberries through a sieve?  Are you cooking the blackberries with some sugar first?  Are you blending them before forcing them through the sieve?

Comment: What is your expectation of a coulis? Where I live, coulis is just a fancy word for mash or purée. Using a fork and sieve like you have done, I would rather expect to get a blackberry juice.

Answer (score 2):

Xanthan gum if you don't want to modify the flavour.

Or

Boil in heavy sugar syrup if you don't mind sweetening the sauce significantly.

Personally I'd do both, I imagine what you've created it BlackBerry juice without much flavour. I'd first start by boiling the berries in some sugar untill much of the water had evaporated and tasted exactly how I wanted (intense BlackBerry flavour) then if it required use a little xanthan gum to get the right consistency.

Comment: For a classical fruit coulis, the preferred method of thickening is fruit pectin instead of something like xanthan gum.  But usually there is sufficient pectin in the skins of the fruit which is why I asked for clarification about blending them before sieving them.

Comment: The problem with pectin is the need for heat. Which changes the flavour of your sauce. Just depends on what flavour you want in the end. One of my fave gels is strawberry and lime, I make it from seived strawberry and lime juice with a pinch of sugar. Thickened with xanthan gum. No heat at all which retains the beautiful summertime flavour but useable as a plate decoration instead of a puddle of water. If I used the traditional pectin way it would be sweet and have jam flavour properties which isn't always preferable. Like I said, it all depends on what is required flavour wise.

Comment: I would argue that a "classical" fruit coulis is prepared by cooking fruit with sugar to form a sweetened fruit reduction that is strained.  I used that terminology to separate what I was referring to from a sweetened fruit purée.  I offered that as a recommendation in the absence of clarification from the original poster.  In a cooked classical fruit coulis, the pectin from mashed pectin-containing fruit like blackberries contributes to the desirable consistency in the reduction so additional pectin is rarely necessary.

Comment: I think this discussion has stemmed from the OPs lack of information, context and follow up. I agree you are right with you expectations of a classic I was addressing the fact he described something more of a water than puree. Never mind can't imagine we will actually hear back from the questioner...

Comment: Thank you Doug! I tried mixing the juice with a 50% sugar syrup (100ml water + 50 grams of sugar), and the result was very satisfactory in texture, however too sweet for my taste. I will try the Xantham gum. I agree with @StephenEure, I didn't make a coulis, just a juice, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That is exactly what I meant :-) get the flavour the way you want then thicken with xanthan gum as it won't change the flavour in any way.